# Bootstrap-select background color when an option is selected

Tags: bootstrap-select

In my SELECT when I select an option only the inner part becomes yellow. I would like the whole select field to turn yellow.

This is my code:

```css
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle:not([title=""]) .filter-option {
      background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-size="40px" data-width="210px" 
    style="height: 80px" data-live-search="true" data-none-Selected-Text="" 
    data-hide-disabled="true" data-container="body" name="mittente_nucleo" 
    id="mittente_nucleo">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pL29zfjn/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color with an jQuery event

```
$('#mittente_nucleo').on('change', function(){
           var selected = $('#mittente_nucleo option:selected').val();
           var element = $('button[data-id="mittente_nucleo"]');
           element.css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yrtd7oa4/

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks